# Is it possible to have the remote host name appear in X11 windows?

Tags: unity, xorg, virtualization, x11-forwarding

I found that running applications over X11 from remote virtual machines give a lot better performance than VNC or Spice.  However, it can get confusing when you have a bunch of windows open on your desktop and some are locally running and others are remotely running.

In the old days, window managers would put the remote host name in the title bar of the window.  Any way to get that to happen in Unity on Ubuntu 12.04 / 12.10?

Comment: As soon as I typed the question it occurred to me that there is probably a compiz plugin for that...and there is.  `Title Bar Plugin`.  Oh well -- I'll leave the question up anyway for the next person.

Comment: Why not add an answer and accept it? That way it will clean the Unanswered Question list up and make it clear that you solved it.

Comment: For some reason thought there was a waiting period...but thats to mark it as the accepted answer....thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As soon as I typed the question it occurred to me that there is probably a compiz plugin for that...and there is. `Title Bar Plugin`